# Constraint Layout working anomalously in API 22

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

While using  *Constraint Layout*, all the activities in API 22 supported phone are going out of the frame whereas it looks perfect in other API levels above 22. The minimum SDK level of the app is 21. I can't understand why is it happening as *Constraint Layout* is perfectly supported by API 22.

**Layout which is inflated**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_image_recycler_inflated_main_activity"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.095"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
/>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="233dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:id="@+id/username_recycler_inflated_main_activity" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/user_image_recycler_inflated_main_activity"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/user_image_recycler_inflated_main_activity"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.017"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:hint="Username"
/>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="233dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:id="@+id/email_recycler_inflated_main_activity"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/username_recycler_inflated_main_activity"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/user_image_recycler_inflated_main_activity"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/username_recycler_inflated_main_activity"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username_recycler_inflated_main_activity"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:hint="timestamp"
/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.two.pilots.messengerappkotlin"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

//  Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'

//  circle image view
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

//  picasso
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

//  groupie
implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.xwray:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:2.3.0'

//  image compressor
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'

implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

**API 22, API 24, API 26 respectively**

[image]

Comment: Some info on your layout would be helpful. It's hard to debug simply on an image.

Comment: @Cheticamp please see the edit

Comment: where is end tag </ConstraintLayout>?

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me. Try dropping back to a production version of `ConstraintLayout`, say, 1.1.3. You _may_ be getting an issue with the 2.0.0-alpha03 release.

Comment: Changed the `Constraint Layout` version to _1.1.3_ but still, this problem persists. I have run this app on other real devices having different API levels and found out that this issue is happening only with the real devices irrespective of the API level.

Comment: I tried in a virtual device with lower resolution and I think the problem is with the reolution of the device. Can you suggest a way to counter this?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand simply by looking at an image but I don't think it is because of the API Level but it might be due to different screen sizes between the devices you have tested your app on.

Make sure your app supports multiple screen sizes.
If you are loading images make sure they fit the device resolution you use and that everything is well constrained.

Answer (score 0):

Change width of the `TextViews` as 0dp. Nothing wrong with the gradle. The problem is with the layout. It is not responsive.

Comment: If it would be a Linear Layout then this approach would have worked but it won't work with Constraint Layout.

Comment: no setting width as 0dp in constraint layout will fill the space between the start and end constraints.